# The build is configured to run SonarQube analysis but the SonarQube analysis targets could not be located

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I am new to .Net and new to SonarScanner with MS Build. I am looking forward for your help on resolving the error I get when I build the project after sonarscanner-msbuild begin process .

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\14.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore\SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets(62,5): error : The build is configured to run SonarQube analysis but the SonarQube analysis targets could not be located. Project: XYZ.csproj [E:\jenkins\workspace\XYZ\XYZ.csproj]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tips and clues:

1. Ensure you have run `SonarScanner.MsBuild begin` before executing `MsBuild`
2. Run `MsBuild` with `/v:diagnostic` switch to get detailed troubleshooting log. In the log lookup `SonarQubeTargetsPath` and `SonarQubeTargetFilePath` values.
3. In case of this or another configuration difficulty see my tutorial on how to setup SonarQube in .NET ecosystem: https://blog.pragmasoft.pl/software/2018-10-10-sonarqube-2-setup-environment/

Comment: +1 for this one as it helped resolving my issue; thought I would share my case to help further: in my case the error was caused by clean and restore being run after the 'begin' command. I fixed by making sure only build runs between 'begin' and 'end'.